# Some best practice questions about C# Unmanaged object Disposing

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, mono, garbage-collection

I am developing mono and .net applications. I have some basic questions regarding the best practices.

1. If I need to create an unmanaged object just to be used once (may be pass to a method or invoke one of it's method) and don't need it later, should I assign it to a variable first and then use it so that I can dispose it (or may be assign variable in a `using()` block) or should I just use like `new Class().Method()`, in order for GC to be able to collect it? What is the best practice?
2. Do I need to dispose of objects which has only a local scope of a method or is it enough if I dispose of object that are properties of the class (global)?
3. I have a Class A and a Class B. An object of B is created in some method M of Class A. This object (of class B) has another method M2 which invokes a second method in Class A, M3. So structure is as below

   ```
   Class A
   {
     void M()
     {
      var b = new B();
      }
     public string M3()
     {
       return "OK";
      }
     }
     Class B
     {
       void M2()
       {
        Console.WriteLine(new A().M3();
        }
      }
   ```

Will this create a cyclic reference a stop GC from collecting these two objects?

What are the other general principles for good Memory efficient programming?

Comment: This is all managed code. The near-only time you really need to get involved in memory management and object disposal is working with unmanaged resources (use `IDisposable` with `using` to save many headaches or alternately try/finally with every use ensuring dispose called) or you are managing resource connections, like a database connection or stream (that most likely implements IDisposable, so a well-placed `using` saves you there as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has a significant risk of becoming "too broad", i.e. off-topic for StackOverflow. That said, some *brief* answers:

> 1. If I need to create an unmanaged object just to be used once (may be pass to a method or invoke one of it's method) and don't need it later… What is the best practice?

Best-practice for using any unmanaged object is to wrap it in an instance of `SafeHandle`. Of course, most common unmanaged objects you'd have to deal with are already wrapped by .NET, either in some custom implementation of `IDisposable` (e.g. `StreamReader`), or in newer framework code, as a `SafeHandle` subclass.

But when you are dealing with your own unmanaged objects that .NET has no knowledge of, you'll want to follow .NET's example and use `SafeHandle`.

> 2. Do I need to dispose of objects which has only a local scope of a method or is it enough if I dispose of object that are properties of the class (global)?

If you create the object, and you have not passed it to some other code for it to own, and you are not going to return it from the method, then you need to dispose it. You *do* need to dispose objects which are referenced only within a method.

Typically you would use the `using` statement to do this.

> 3. …Will this create a cyclic reference a stop GC from collecting these two objects?

Ignoring for a moment that your code example wouldn't compile, nor contains any reference cycles… :)

Unlike some memory management schemes, such as ref-counting, .NET's garbage collection does not have any issue with cyclical references at all. An object is determined to be collectable or not based on whether it is reachable from a *root* reference. Two unrooted objects which reference each other are still neither reachable from a root reference and so are both collectable.

> What are the other general principles for good Memory efficient programming?

That's definitely too broad for StackOverflow. Even in the GC-based system .NET uses, there a lot of fine details that one can concern oneself with. The basic system eliminates a number of common programming errors, but it has its own idiosyncratic behaviors that are in some cases important to understand.

Some time spent browsing MSDN and web articles on the topic will help you learn more about garbage collection, in .NET and in general. If and when you have other *specific* questions, please feel free to post them on StackOverflow.

Comment: That answered almost all my questions. I think I need to re-frame my first question. It is a bit mis-leading to what I actually meant to ask.                         My scenario is that I need the scope of an unmanaged object only for one line of code. I can use it either like new ClassName().Method() or (var obj = new ClassName(){obj.method;} My question is does the first option create an object and keep in object graph or does it not as it is not being assigned to a variable ? If it does not is not, is not that a better practice ? Otherwise it should allocate a memory that we can' dispose ?

Comment: @Sreeraj: I'm not sure what you mean; your example doesn't seem to have an unmanaged object. But ignoring that, the answer is: it doesn't matter. Either way, an object is allocated. And either way, the GC will get rid of it as soon as it sees you are not going to use it again. The variable is irrelevant; the GC can even collect an object even if it's theoretically referenced by e.g. a local variable, as long as the JIT-compiler optimizer has figured out that the object actually is never referenced past a certain point.

Comment: @Sreeraj: (continued...)  Of course, if you write code like that where `ClassName` implements `IDisposable` and you don't dispose the object, that's a bug. And you won't be able to dispose of the object unless you save the value in a variable, preferably declared as part of a `using` statement. But it's not clear whether that's part of your question or not. The example doesn't seem to involve `IDisposable`.

Comment: The second portion of the comment answered my question perfectly. Thank You . I wanted to know if that style would allocate some memory as it is not assigned to a variable. Now I understood. I should assign all unmanaged object to a variable, so that they can be disposed